# Using range slider to change div height

Tags: javascript, css

Seen examples using the range input to control rotation of a div with javascript, but cant see how to change it to other properties such as height and opacity. Here is an example:

```
function rotate(value)
{
x=document.getElementById('div1')
x.style.webkitTransform="rotate(" + value + "deg)"; 
}


<input type="range" min="0" max="360" value="0" onchange="rotate(this.value)">
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a more generalized solution, you can create a generic `setStyleOn` method. [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yC2AT/1/)

JS:

```
function setStyleOn(rule, targetId, value) {
    x = document.getElementById(targetId);
    x.style[rule] = value;
}
```

HTML:

```
<label>Rotation</label>
<input type="range" min="0" max="360" value="0" 
    onchange="setStyleOn('webkitTransform', 'div1', 'rotate(' + this.value + 'deg')">
<label>Opacity</label>
<input type='range' min='0' max='1.0' value='1.0' step='0.1' 
    onchange="setStyleOn('opacity', 'div1', this.value)" />
<label>Height</label>
<input type='range' min='0' max='100' value='10' step='1' 
    onchange="setStyleOn('height', 'div1', this.value + 'em')" />    
<label>Width</label>
<input type='range' min='0' max='100' value='10' step='1' 
    onchange="setStyleOn('width', 'div1', this.value + 'em')" />    
<div id="div1">
</div>
```

Comment: Ah ok great, is there a way to to make the change more 'real time' it only updates when I release the slider?

Comment: Yes, instead of using the onchange event, you'll have to use the oninput event. Problem is that oninput isn't supported by IE < 9. It's probably best to have both oninput and onchange in the html to allow IE < 9 browsers to have the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function divHeight(value)
{
    var x = document.getElementById('div1');
    x.style.height=value+"px"; 
}
</script>


<input type="range" min="0" value="0" onchange="divHeight(this.value)">
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many functions explained for example on [this site](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp).

For changing height: you can use scale(), for moving position: translate(), for skewing shape: skew() etc...

For opacity, use [opacity property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_opacity.asp).